# f:facet - there is a list of predefined names attributes?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, tags, facet, names

I have searched across the web with no luck, I know there are some predefined names, such as 'header' and 'footer' associated with the dataTable, also 'first' inside the head tag to run first this metatag.

There are other predefined names I should be aware of?

Thanks,
-M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot find a predefined names list for facets. because facets are related to components. Every components supports different facets. e.g. h:datatable supports header and footer. primefaces datatable supports header, footer and emptyMessage facets. best way to find supportted facets you should look source code of component renderers. [Primefaces DatatableRenderer](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.primefaces/primefaces/4.0/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTableRenderer.java), [Mojarra TableRenderer](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.4/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/TableRenderer.java)

Comment: You can sometimes deduce something from the showcase or documentation as well

Comment: It would be nice to know what exactly to search for in the source code. My guess would be to search for the `getFacet` method calls, I might be wrong. Updated link to the source code https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces